# beginner: Stemming in pandas produces letters not stems

Tags: pandas

My column 'tokens' is already tokenised and is a list:

```
['super', 'tolles', 'team', 'nochmals', 'danke']
```

I stem using:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
german_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('german', ignore_stopwords=True)
df_de['stemmed'] = df_de['tokens'].apply(lambda x: [german_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
```

I get letters instead of words and a list within a list with two starting square brackets. What is the easy cure for this problem?

```
'stemmed'
[[, ', s, u, p, e, r, ', ,,  , ', t, o, l, l, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The data frame `apply` already applies the function to each cell in the column you selected. So you're applying to each word, say `super`, and then iterating it:

```
for y in x
```

which is like

```
for y in 'super'
```

Iterating a word goes letter by letter. What you want is to apply the stemmer to the entire cell:

```
df_de['tokens'].apply(lambda x: german_stemmer.stem(x))
```

or better yet

```
df_de['tokens'].apply(german_stemmer.stem)
```

Comment: the output is ['super', 'tolles', 'team', 'nochmals', 'danke'] . when I do it properly on a single list       tokens = ['super', 'tolles', 'team', 'nochmals', 'danke']
german_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('german', ignore_stopwords=True)
stemmed = [german_stemmer.stem(x) for x in tokens]
I get what I expect to get: ['sup', 'toll', 'team', 'nochmal', 'dank']

Comment: @falco_tinnunculus as stated, your question is incomplete. Write a complete, **minimal** code we can use for reproduction/.

Comment: I have now solved the problem. I was reading the column tokens from a file and it was not interpreted as a list but as a string. I added df_de.tokens.apply(literal_eval) and the code worked as it was, i.e. df_de['stemmed'] = df_de['tokens'].apply(lambda x: [german_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
Please mark as solved